# Is there a way to create custom device profile for Microsoft's Android Emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

Since Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft has [release](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) it's very own Android emulator.

One of the feature I find very appealing from it is that it provide full-speed emulation and does not require Hyper-V to be turned off. Unlike Android's Intel HAXM emulator which require Hyper-V to be off.

Much of developer workflow now involve running services on Docker which requires Hyper-V to be enabled to run, and then consuming said services from apps often running on emulators. Having to repeatedly flip system switch is a deal breaker.

Having said that, I don't seem to be able to find ways to write custom device profile for MS Android Emulator (akin to AVD maybe). All that is available are profiles provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Have you found a way to create custom profiles by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I've googled around but nothing turns up. I ended up ditching MS Android Emulator, Docker for Windows, and disabling Hyper-V all the time.  Back to HAXM and Docker Toolkit with VirtualBox